# What i need to add to automaticaly update textBox2 with a LineCounter for the textBox1 input?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

My goal is to get the line/rows counter of the textBox1 input into textBox2 and display/update it in real time.
So far it work's only if I click and type something in textBox2.

```
private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.textBox1 = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
        this.textBox2 = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // textBox1
        // 
        this.textBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(288, 47);
        this.textBox1.Multiline = true;
        this.textBox1.Name = "textBox1";
        this.textBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(301, 193);
        this.textBox1.TabIndex = 0;
        this.textBox1.TextChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.textBox1_TextChanged);
        // 
        // textBox2
        // 
        this.textBox2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(544, 265);
        this.textBox2.Name = "textBox2";
        this.textBox2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(45, 20);
        this.textBox2.TabIndex = 1;
        this.textBox2.TextChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.textBox2_TextChanged);
```

And here is the Form()

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        
    }

private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string strtext = textBox1.Text;
        var textArr = strtext.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        textBox2.Text = textArr.Length.ToString();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This code:

```cs
string strtext = textBox1.Text;
var textArr = strtext.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
textBox2.Text = textArr.Length.ToString();
```

Should all be in the `textBox1_TextChanged` function and not in the `textBox2_TextChanged` function, because you want to execute that code when the text in textBox1 changes.

Answer (score -1):

You might not need such a complex code. The textbox has a Lines property that returns an array of the lines:

```
lineCountLabel.Text = editorTextBox.Lines.Count.ToString();
```

but I recall that it performs the same as you do there; splits the content to an array, which is an *incredibly* expensive operation to perform *every time* the user presses a key especially if the textbox is long. The numbers of string allocations your program will perform, constantly splitting a string into an array and throwing it away, just to get a count, is incredible waste of resources

Instead I recommend you just count the newlines:

```
lineCountLabel.Text = editorTextBox.Text.Count(c => c == '\n').ToString();
```

And if your textbox has a lot of text only perform this when they stop typing: out a timer on the form with an interval of 1 second, disable and enable the timer in the TextChanged (it resets the timeout) and put the count code in the timer tick event. Also stop the timer in the tick event

---

ps: noticed you have a logic to remove empty entries which, if intended, I suppose means you're only counting sentences rather than lines. Consider, if that's what you want, something like:

```
int c = 0; int p = Environment.NewLine.Length; int s = lineCountLabel.Text; int n = Environment.NewLine.Last();

for(int x = p; x<s.Length-1; x++)
  if(s[x] == n && s[x-p] != n)
    c++;

lineCountLabel.Text = c.ToString();
```

This could be done with LINQ, but it's a bit messy